# how to write Query Login page servlet from data base

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

```
package java4s;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class OnServletLogin extends HttpServlet {

    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/STUDENTS";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Database..");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql = "SELECT id, userId, password FROM login";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


            PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
            res.setContentType("text/html");

            String user = req.getParameter("userName");
            String pass = req.getParameter("userPassword");

            pw.print("<font face='verdana'>");

            if (user.equals("select * from login where userId="+user+"and password"+pass) )
                pw.println("Login Success...!");
            else
                pw.println("Login Failed...!");

            pw.print("</font>");
            pw.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Hi this is my code, I am trying to implement a login page from database, but I am unable to put the logic for login from database data. I create table `login` in that I have 2 fields `user id` and `password.` But how to retrieve and how fetch so that I can enable login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the below code,

```
String user = req.getParameter("userName");
  String pass = req.getParameter("userPassword");
  String id=null;
  String userId=null;

  String sql = "SELECT id, userId, password FROM login where username='"+user+"' and password='"+pass+"'";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next())
 {
 id=rs.getString("id");
userId=rs.getString("userId");   
}

if(id!=null)
System.out.println("Login Success");
else
System.out.println("Login Failed");
```

**UPDATE:**
Try using prepared statement instead of directly passing values to sql query.

Eg.

```
PreparedStatement pst = null;
String sql = "SELECT id, userId, password FROM login where username=? and password=?";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1,user);
pst.setString(2,pass);
ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from TABLE where userid=blah AND password=blah

if exactly one matching row exists then go ahead with it and let the dude log in by setting session variables that would otherwise redirect the user from other pages and stuff.

So something along the lines of [This example on has a username, no password]

```
        String user = request.getParameter("username");

        String sqlStr = "select * FROM customers WHERE name = " + "\"" + user
                + "\"";

        out.println("<p>You query is: " + sqlStr + "</p>"); // Echo for //
                                                            // debugging
        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(sqlStr); // Send the query to the
                                                    // // server
        boolean hasResult = rset.next();
        if (hasResult) {
            out.println("Logged in!");
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
            session.setAttribute("USER", user);
            String role = rset.getString("role");

            if (role.equals("owner")) {
                response.sendRedirect("categories.jsp");
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("productsbrowsing.jsp");
            }
        } else {
            out.println("User not found");
        }
```

Comment: But where i have write this?

Comment: I updated my answer. Are you sure you don't know where to write that? O: It should be clear? It is all procedural, but I dunno. Let me know if you still have questions, yo

Answer (score 0):

In the login page,create a form that accepts username and password.This form should call a servlet where you need to get the entered username and password using this way

```
request.getParameter("username");
request.getParameter("password");
```

Then get the original username and password from the database.Match with this one.If matches then create a session and forward to next page else send to login page

```
<form action ="one_servlet" >
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password"
<input type="submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("Database..");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String db_username = null;
        String db_password = null;
            query = "SELECT username, password FROM login;";
            stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

            while(rs.next()){
                db_username = rs.getString("username");
                db_password = rs.getString("password");
                //check null's also 
                if(dbUsername.equals(username) && dbPassword.equals(password)){
                   System.out.println("sucess");

                }

            }
        }  catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please update My code am really new in Sql to database connction

Answer (score 0):

Please use PreparedStatemen to Fix SQL Injection......

Read the below artices.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/11/sql-injection-in-java-application.html

http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

```
      try {
            String user = req.getParameter("userName");
            String pass = req.getParameter("userPassword");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Database..");
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id, userId, password FROM login WHERE userId=? AND password=?");
            stmt.setString(1, user);
            stmt.setString(2, pass);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
            res.setContentType("text/html");        

            pw.print("<font face='verdana'>");

           if (rs.next() ) {
                pw.println("Login Success...!");
            else
                pw.println("Login Failed...!");

            pw.print("</font>");
            pw.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package java4s;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class OnServletLogin extends HttpServlet {

static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/STUDENTS";
static final String USER = "root";
static final String PASS = "";

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("Database..");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from login where userid=? and password=?"); 



        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");

        String user = req.getParameter("userName");
        String pass = req.getParameter("userPassword");
        ps.setString(1,user);
        ps.setString(2,pass);
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

        pw.print("<font face='verdana'>");

        if(rs.next())
          pw.println("Login Success...!");
        else
          pw.println("Login Failed...!");



        pw.print("</font>");
        pw.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

}

> try this one , i have edited your code